# printing HTML and inserting variables using python-flask

Tags: python, html, flask, pymongo

Im trying to print html code that will also include variables, in this case its data from database with this code:

```
def displayHot():
myCursor = mongo.db.posts.find()
for result_object in myCursor:
        print''' 
        Content-Type: text/html

        <div class="card-header">
        <h3 %s
        </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
        <p> %s 
        </p>
        <a class="panel-google-plus-image" href="{{url_for('Images', filename = 'Images/%s')}}"
        </a>
        </div" 
        ''' % (result_object['uploader'], result_object['description'], result_object['file_name'])
```

and rendering it here:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', function = displayHot())
```

when i run it, i get the printed data in my cmd.. so my question is how can i print the html code so it will act as html code and not just a print command in cmd

Comment: If you need to use something outside of a function, you need to return it, not print it.

Comment: Your indentation in displayHot function is wrong. 
Could you show your printed data and index.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you would be better served by doing your looping in a jinja template, and just sending the template the data for the loop.  Something like this is what I'm thinking:

#### Python code

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        myCursor = mongo.db.posts.find()
        return render_template('index.html', cursor = myCursor)
```

#### index.html

```
<!-- your other code here -->
{% for result_object in cursor %}
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3> {{result_object['uploader']}}
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
        <p> {{result_object['description']}}
        </p>
        <a class="panel-google-plus-image" href="{{url_for('Images', filename = '''Images/result_object['file_name']''')}}"
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<!-- the rest of your html -->
```

This is simplified, and you would likely need to do more in order to get `myCursor` set up properly before sending it to the template, but I hope that gets the idea across.